# Use access token from backend in next-auth

Tags: next.js, next-auth

I have a backend written on nest js + graphql and there I have written such a method for authorization:

```
@Public()
@Mutation(() => Auth)
async signIn(@Args('data') data: SignInInput): Promise<Auth> {
  return this.authService.signIn(data);
}
```

service:

```
async signIn(signInInput: SignInInput): Promise<Auth> {
  console.log(signInInput)

const user = await this.userService.findOneByEmail(signInInput.email)

const isPasswordValid = await verify(user.password, signInInput.password)

if (!isPasswordValid) {
  throw new UnauthorizedException("Неверный пароль!")
}

const { accessToken, refreshToken } = await this.tokenService.generate({ id: user.id, role: user.role })
return { user, tokens: { accessToken, refreshToken } }

  }
```

And my code in next-auth looks like this:

```
import { fetchLogin } from '@/Repository/Hooks/auth-hooks'
import NextAuth, { type NextAuthOptions } from 'next-auth'
import CredentialsProvider from 'next-auth/providers/credentials'
import { NextResponse } from 'next/server'

export const authOptions: NextAuthOptions = {
  pages: {
    signIn: '/'
  },
  providers: [
    CredentialsProvider({
      name: "Sign in",
      credentials: {
        email: {
          label: "Email",
          type: "email",
          placeholder: 'hello@example.com'
        },
        password: { label: "Password", type: 'password' }
      },
      async authorize(credentials) {
        if (!credentials?.email || !credentials.password) {
          return null
        }
        
        const res = await fetchLogin(credentials.email, credentials.password)
        if (res.tokens.accessToken && res.tokens.refreshToken) {
          return res
        }
        else {
          return null
        }
      }
    })
  ],
  session: {
    strategy: 'jwt'
  },
  callbacks: {
    async jwt({ token, user }) {
      return { ...token, ...user }
    },
    async session({ session, token }) {
      session.user = token as any
      return session
    }
  }
}

const handler = NextAuth(authOptions)
export { handler as GET, handler as POST }
```

And response from server

```
{
  "tokens": {
    "accessToken": "someotken1",
    "refreshToken": "sometoken2"
  },
  "user": {
    "createdAt": "2024-01-29T16:39:26.917Z",
    "email": "test@mail.ru",
    "id": "66c3de63-9fef-4e78-b6ba-7ce1a9965b88",
    "name": "Test",
    "provider": null,
    "role": "ADMIN",
    "updatedAt": "2024-01-30T15:36:32.661Z",
    "cart": null,
    "favorites": [],
    "orders": []
  },
  "iat": 1706629591,
  "exp": 1709221591,
  "jti": "f9b90840-f65e-4180-91d9-ff77487f3a76"
}
```

The problem is that next-auth itself generates the token and puts it in the cookie instead of what the backend returns. How to make it so that we take the accessToken from the server response?